# C++ 2d array when subtracting 1 from col in position 0 it goes back a row to last spot in col

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm making a reversi game in c++ and whenever I use a 10 by 10 array and search within the array to switch letters the game likes to switch up my rows and columns. This output would cause the o to switch to an x.

. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . . .

. . . . . . . . x o

x . . . . . . . . .

Comment: what is position 0? what rows are you talking about. Can you instead mention the indices?

Comment: Exactly what were you expecting to happen, when you subtracted 1 from position 0?

Comment: Position 0 0 would be the top left and going right would be (0,1), (0,2)

Comment: So if I subtract 1 from position 0 it will subtract one row and begin at the last column?